# How to Add TinyMCE textbox using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, tinymce

I want my user to select templateId from the select list, when user select then query the database to bring the template Contents based on templateId . Then I would like show the Template Content to textarea but it shows the html tags in the TinyMCE textarea rather showing the Design (View).

It works only when I show the same templateContents on page load but when I try to show the same contents by getting from the database it fails.

Hope it all gives you any clue what I required.

In step 1 the code is working fine...

```php
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 50%">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($ResultArray[0]['Contents']); ?>
</textarea>
```

...but onchange value of select I am calling selected template:

```php
<select name="templateId" id="templateId" onchange="GetTemplateView(this.value);">
    <?php for($i=0; $i<count($ResultArray); $i++){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ResultArray[$i]['TemplateId']; ?>"><?php echo $ResultArray[$i]['Name']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Ajax request is:

```js
function GetTemplateView(templateId)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {   // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
                document.getElementById("templateView").outerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            else
                document.getElementById("templateView").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "js/GetTemplateView.php?id=" + templateId + "&encode=true", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

GetTemplateView.php:

```php
<?php
include_once("../classes/db_utility_class.php");
$ClassObj= new Cdb();
$input        =   $_GET["id"];
$Encode       =   $_GET["encode"];

if($input!=0)
{
    $query = "SELECT Contents FROM mailtemplate WHERE TemplateId=".$input;
    $result = $ClassObj->getRowFromDB($query);
    if($result != "Error in query" || $result != "No Record Found")
    {
        if($Encode)
        {
            echo '<textarea id="ele1" name="ele1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 50%">';
            echo htmlspecialchars($result['Contents']);
            echo '</textarea>';
        }
        else
            echo $result['Contents'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly  use jquery.ajax more easy to use .

And 1.  store the tinyMCE to a variable in a processpage.php .

1. and in the success function of your ajax call append it to any div or body where you want it to show .

Look at the example code .call it when you want .

```
<script>
             $.ajax({
                url: processpage.php, 
                type: 'GET',                     
                contentType: 'text/html',
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                data:{
                                    showTINYMCE : 'Yes'
                                },
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $('body').append(msg);
                },
                error: function (msg) 
                {
                }
            });

</script>
```

In your processpage.php :

```
if($_GET['showTINYMCE'] == 'Yes')
{
$tinymce = "contains the tinymce";     
echo $tinymce;
}
```

this will do it .

Comment: How I would be able to send select control's value to processpage.php

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to say about "select controls value" . Then only i can give you a answer